# Add a note explaining how to switch your main election vote

Tags: feature-request, voting, election

Currently there is a [moderator election going on in Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/4) and it's in the main portion of it where you choose specific candidates for positions ordered First, Second, Third.

I voted in it moments ago, but I accidentally put the wrong candidate in position First, and it was not immediately apparent how to switch a different candidate to that position (there was no close "x" in the corner, or a cancel button).  After a brief experimentation, I did figure out how to correct my vote: the actual task of switching a candidate is done by simply selecting anyone else for the position.

This isn't obvious.

I think there should be a single sentence explaining how to switch your vote (similar to *"To switch your vote in the main election, simply select a different candidate for that position."*) somewhere on the page, possibly towards the bottom of the election sidebar.